# EditPad: how use Replace with RegExp strings and Carriage Returns

Tags: regex, editpad

I have the next text:

```
hola este es un test.
Test de regexp.
Super man
es un héroe de comic.
Test nueva linea
```

And the result I expected If there are a dot (.), then a carriage return and then a word (A-Za-z), put inside a extra Carriage Returns. Example:

```
hola este es un test.

Test de regexp.

Super man
es un héroe de comic.

Test nueva linea
```

How do you do in EditPad Pro replace Panel? I think that I need use Backreferences.

Answer (score 2):

Regex:

```
(\.\r?\n)([A-Za-z])
```

or

```
(\.[\r\n]+)([A-Za-z])
```

Replace with:

```
\1\n\2
```

if `\1` or `\2` won't work then use `$1`, `$2` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Backreferences may not be needed:

```
\.\n
```

...replaced with...

```
\.\n\n
```

...may be good enough.  The case where you may want a backreference is if you want to be sure that you don't add an extra newline if there's no following text.  In that case:

```
\.\n([a-zA-Z])
```

...replaced with...

```
\.\n\n\1
```

...should be what you need.

Note, I'm not using EditPad Pro, and different editors use different terminology for backreferences, so it may be `\.\n\n$1` instead.